# Win7 and CentOS in dualboot mode

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot

It's my first time installing two systems in a dual-boot configuration. I have them both on a single hard drive. When installing linux, I requested to place grub in a bootable area of linux partition rather then MBR, grub has identified Windows7 on the other partition and added grub.conf. However after rebooting PC, it still boots in Windows7, so I had to install EasyBSD to have a choice of boot between linux or windows.

Now, I'd like to get rid of EasyBCD, and stay with grub. Is it possible to have grub dual-boot my systems? (I've read lots in Internet, and most recommend to use EasyBCD). But I think if I make linux partition bootable (with fdisk /dev/sda, and pressing 'a' in the menu), I should be able to have what I want -- upon reset, control goes to grub and I select what to boot further.

Am I right thinking so, or there's something I'm missing and there's some specifics with Windows7-Linux dual-boot?

Thanks.

Comment: Run [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) from within Linux.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed grub to a primary partition then you can restore the "legacy" bootloader to the MBR and mark the partition that grub is installed on as "active". This will cause the legacy bootloader to chain to grub.

Comment: thanks for response. What is "legacy" bootloader that you're referring to? I didn't touch

Comment: @Mark please register your account on [SU] and [SF]. That will give you ownership of the migrated question, allowing you to make comments on answers. If you create a Stack Exchange account using the same email that you entered when you asked the question, everything will automatically be associated to your new account.